# An additive map that is not a linear transformation over $\mathbb{R}$, when $\mathbb{R}$ is considered as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On sort-of-linear functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16175/on-sort-of-linear-functions)

I am looking for an example of an additive map that is not a linear transformation over $\mathbb{R}$, when $\mathbb{R}$ is considered as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. I mean, I want to find an example of a map $T:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$ for all $u,v\in \mathbb{R}$, but $T(\alpha v)=\alpha T(u)$ is not true for all $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: Pick a basis; use the basis.

Comment: I assume you mean linear over $\mathbb{Q}$, in which case you should replace "for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$" by "for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$"...

Comment: @MTurgeon: I believe spohreis wants a map that is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear but *not* $\mathbb{R}$-linear, so "for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$" is correct, since it is prefaced by "is **not** true"

Comment: possible duplicate of [On sort-of-linear functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16175/on-sort-of-linear-functions) and [A discontinuous linear function over the rationals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23069/a-discontinuous-linear-function-over-the-rationals)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Fair enough; I just noticed that additivity implies $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $\{r_\alpha\}$ be a Hamel basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$. Let $\phi$ map $x$ to $c_{\alpha_1}+\cdots+c_{\alpha_k}$, where the (unique) basis representation of $x$ is $c_{\alpha_1}r_{\alpha_1}+\cdots+c_{\alpha_k}r_{\alpha_k}$. Then $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$, but takes on only rational values.

If $\phi(\alpha v)=\alpha\phi(v)$ for all $\alpha$, $v$ in $\Bbb R$, then $\phi$ would be onto.
As this isn't the case,  $\phi$ is not $\Bbb R$-linear.

It is $\Bbb Q$-linear, though.  In fact, any additive map would automatically be $\Bbb Q$-linear.

As far as I know, you need the axiom of choice to construct a function of this type (?).

Comment: [Andres Caicedo's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16175/on-sort-of-linear-functions#comment35888_16175) on a [closely related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/16175/) supports your last sentence.