# If $T:V\to W$ preserves addition then is $T$ linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V,W$ be vector spaces and $T:V\to W$ be a map between them.

> If $T$ preserves addition, i.e. $T(v_1 + v_2)=T(v_1)+T(v_2)$ for all $v_1,v_2\in V$, then is
>   $T$ a linear map?

My instinct tells me no, because otherwise I feel as though it should have been demonstrated in my linear algebra course. However, a mate of mine proved the result when the vector spaces are over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Edit: I am well aware that a linear map need also preserve scalar multiplication. However, I am having difficulty coming up with a counter-example.

Comment: Hint for counterexample: Linearity is not just commutation with addition, but with scalar multiplication as well. So try to create a $T$ that breaks the latter but preserves the former.

Comment: This is true only when your base field is $\Bbb{Q}$ or the finite fields of the type $\Bbb{Z}/(p)$

Comment: By definition, a linear map between vector spaces is a map that preserves addition AND scalar multiplication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An additive map that is not a linear transformation over $\mathbb{R}$, when $\mathbb{R}$ is considered as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106785/an-additive-map-that-is-not-a-linear-transformation-over-mathbbr-when-ma)

Comment: Check out [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result is not true in general. Consider 
$$ T:\mathbb{C}^1\to\mathbb{C}^1$$
given by 
$$ T(a+bi)=a.$$
It is additive:
$$ T(a+bi+c+di)=T(a+c+(b+d)i)=(a+c)=T(a+bi)+T(c+di).$$
It is not, however, homogeneous.
$$ T(i)=0\implies iT(i)=0$$
But,
$$T(i*i)=T(-1)=-1\ne 0 .$$
So, $iT(i)\ne T(i*i)$. This is an additive non-homogeneous function.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider $T\colon \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ given by $T(z) = \overline{z}$. It always preserves addition. But if you consider $\Bbb C$ as a complex vector space, it is not linear (i.e., it is not $\Bbb C-$linear). If you view $\Bbb C$ as a real vector space, it is linear (i.e., it is $\Bbb R-$linear).