# Additive but not multiplicative

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I am looking for a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that it admits
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ but there exist $\alpha,x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(\alpha x)\neq\alpha f(x).$$ All I know is that the function is hard to contruct.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106785/an-additive-map-that-is-not-a-linear-transformation-over-mathbbr-when-ma/106790#106790).

Comment: What happen if we consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$? Can you give a short comment?

Comment: @Sukan nothing happens, it is a one-dimensional vector space, hence boring ;)