# Importance of the homogeneity assumption in definition of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over field $F$.  A function $f: V \rightarrow W$ is said to be linear if for any two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $V$ and any scalar $\alpha\in F$, the following two conditions are satisfied:

1. $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$
2. $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$

Let $F$ be a field of real numbers. Is it possible to construct $f$ such that the first condition is satified but not the second one?

Comment: The axiom is there for a reason. You can show that assuming (1), $f$ has to be homogeneous with respect to elements on $\mathbb Q$. I would pick $V = W = \mathbb R$ and play around with this fact.

Comment: There might be also some connections with max-plus algebras and topical functions.

Comment: Possibly related: [Continuous and additive implies linear](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152632/continuous-and-additive-implies-linear)

Comment: Relevant: [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation?lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to construct examples of $f$ that are additive but not homogeneous. However, the construction won't be explicit and depends on the axiom of choice. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16175/on-sort-of-linear-functions) for details.

If you want an **explicit** example of an additive map that is not homogeneous over a different field, let $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$ and consider the map $\varphi \colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by complex conjugation:

$$ \varphi(z) = \varphi(x + iy) = \overline{z} = x - iy. $$

The map $\varphi$ is additive and $\mathbb{R}$-homogeneous but not $\mathbb{C}$-homogeneous as $\varphi(az) = \overline{az} = \overline{a}\overline{z} = \overline{a}\varphi(z)$.

Comment: Is it proven, that the axiom of choice is necessary here? Nice example for complex numbers.

Comment: It is consistent with $ZF$ (without choice) that all additive functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are homogeneous (and so linear) so in this sense the axiom is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ is known as a [Cauchy additive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation). This would be a special case example when $V=W=\mathbb{R}$. Assuming the axiom of choice, there do exist such functions without the property that $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$, but such functions are incredibly ugly, for example they aren't continuous anywhere.

The proof that such functions exist is non-constructive (because it uses the axiom of choice). This means that you can't actually construct an example of one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be omitted. A homomorphism of vector spaces must preserve four operations: addition of vectors, multiplication with scalar, fixing zero vector, taking the inverse of vector.

It is necessary and sufficient that a linear mapping satisfy said axioms.

Comment: It is not so trivial. If F is a field of rational numbers, then the homogeneity axiom is implied by the additivity axiom.

Comment: You are considering a special case. What I have stated applies without loss of generality.